# Detect the Enter key in a text input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a function if enter is pressed while on specific input.

What I'm I doing wrong?

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if ($(".input1").is(":focus") && (e.keyCode == 13)) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

Is there a better way of doing this which would say, if enter pressed on `.input1` do function?

Answer (score 684, accepted):

```
$(".input1").on('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.keyCode === 13) {
        // Do something
    }
});

// e.key is the modern way of detecting keys
// e.keyCode is deprecated (left here for for legacy browsers support)
// keyup is not compatible with Jquery select(), Keydown is.
```

Comment: Which browser were you testing it in? I think older versions of IE don't trigger keyup events on the document (not sure about this though).

Comment: Your code wasnt working because you used .is() and needed === rather than ==. See my answer for some more details.

Comment: BTW If the form happens to submit because youve pressed enter, the keyup event doesnt get fired - the input looses focus. in my firefox.

Comment: I'd recommend to use `$('.input1').on('keyup', function (e) {});` instead for better compatibility.

Comment: Properties `which`, `code`, `charCode` and `keyCode` is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent, please add actual information to your answer.

Answer (score 240):

## event.key === "Enter"

More recent and much cleaner: use `event.key`. **No more arbitrary number codes!**

> NOTE: The old properties (`.keyCode` and `.which`) are Deprecated.

```
const node = document.getElementsByClassName("input1")[0];
node.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        // Do work
    }
});
```

Modern style, with lambda and destructuring

```
node.addEventListener("keyup", ({key}) => {
    if (key === "Enter") {
        // Do work
    }
})
```

If you must use jQuery:

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    if ($(".input1").is(":focus") && event.key == "Enter") {
        // Do work
    }
});
```

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)

Comment: kudos for the plain javascript version, not sure why all the others are in jquery

Comment: Because, the OP put his example code in jQuery and (as well as JavaScript) jQuery is tagged.

Comment: Dear Sirs, in the modern style one, what's the purpose of `{}` around `key`? TIA

Answer (score 44):

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if ($(".input1:focus") && (e.keyCode === 13)) {
       alert('ya!')
    }
 });
```

Or just bind to the input itself

```
$('.input1').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
       alert('ya!')
    }
  });
```

To figure out which keyCode you need, use the website http://keycode.info

Comment: Thank you. I've learned something new. By the way I used .is() ALOT of times so it is not logic, not to be working. Also the ==, again I used two == for other situations

Comment: np, you should always be using ===

Answer (score 14):

Try this to detect the `Enter` key pressed in a textbox.

```
$(function(){

$(".input1").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        // Enter key pressed
    }
 });

});
```

Answer (score 9):

The best way I found is using `keydown` ( the `keyup` doesn't work well for me).

Note: I also disabled the form submit because usually when you like to do some actions when pressing Enter Key the only think you do not like is to submit the form :)

```
$('input').keydown( function( event ) {
    if ( event.which === 13 ) {
        // Do something
        // Disable sending the related form
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: event.keyCode is deprecated event.which is not, so this is better

Answer (score 6):

It may be too late to answer this question. But  the following code simply prevents the enter key. Just copy and paste should work.

```
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function stopRKey(evt) { 
          var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null); 
          var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null); 
          if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text"))  {return false;} 
        } 

        document.onkeypress = stopRKey; 

        </script>
```

Answer (score 5):

The solution that work for me is the following

```
$("#element").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution that worked for me is this:

```
<input onkeydown="if (event.key == 'Enter'){//do logic}else{}">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this to detect the Enter key pressed in a textbox.

```
$(document).on("keypress", "input", function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        alert("Enter key pressed");
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.jquerypot.com/how-to-detect-if-enter-key-is-pressed-in-a-text-input-field-in-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".input1").keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                // Do something
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This code handled every input for me in the whole site. It checks for the ENTER KEY inside an INPUT field and doesn't stop on TEXTAREA or other places.

```
$(document).on("keydown", "input", function(e){
 if(e.which == 13){
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did for my angular project:

HTML:

```
<input
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="searchFirstName"
    (keyup)="keyUpEnter($event)"
/>
```

TypeScript:

```
keyUpEnter(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.key == 'Enter') {
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone need one line solution:

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="(event.key === 'Enter') ? alert('Entered') : undefined;" placeholder="Type Something and Press Enter">
```