# How to detect when the user presses Enter in an input field

Tags: javascript

I only have 1 input field and I want to register onChange and onKeyPress event to detect when the users finish their input or press the Enter key. I need to use javascript only. Thanks for the help.

I have:

```
var load = function (){
   //I want to trigger this function when user hit Enter key.
}

document.getElementById('co').onchange=load;   //works great
document.getElementById('co').onKeyPress=load; 
//not sure how to detect when user press Enter
```

html

```
//no form just a single input field
<input type='text' id='co'>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enter key press event in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/enter-key-press-event-in-javascript)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/7060750/14264568

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('foo').onkeypress = function(e){
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var keyCode = e.code || e.key;
    if (keyCode == 'Enter'){
      // Enter pressed
      return false;
    }
  }
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/aligus/2)

Comment: additional question. How do I access foo element after I detect the user press Enter? I can't use this keyword, it refer to window object. Thanks a lot

Comment: i'd use `if (keyCode === 13)` for strict equals

Comment: Sorry, kindly, what is the aim and the meaning of the first if? `if (!e)` - thank you

Comment: @Robert It means is if `e` is undefined, we will give value to `e` from `window.event`

Comment: Both "keyCode" and "which" are deprecated. Use "code" or "key" these days, and compare it to the string value "Enter".

Comment: May change to:
if (keyCode == 'Enter' || keyCode == 'NumpadEnter')

Answer (score 19):

None of these answers as of yet specifically answer this question.  The question is in 2 parts.  1.  Enter is Pressed. 2. The uses is focused on an input.

**Jquery**

```
$('#input-id').on("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        console.log('Enter');
    }
});
```

**Vanilla JavaScript**

```
inputId = document.getElementById('input-id');
inputId.addEventListener('keyup', function onEvent(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        console.log('Enter')
    }
});
```

This way ENTER is only detected when the user presses enter FROM that input.

Answer (score 14):

More recent and much cleaner: use `event.key` instead of `event.keyCode`. **No more arbitrary number codes!**

```
const node = document.getElementById('co');
node.addEventListener('keydown', function onEvent(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        return false;
    }
});
```

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)

Answer (score 7):

To make it cross browser:

```
document.getElementById('foo').onkeypress = function(e) {
    var event = e || window.event;
    var charCode = event.which || event.keyCode;

    if ( charCode == '13' ) {
      // Enter pressed
      return false;
    }
}
```

See this question for more details: [javascript event e.which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050984/javascript-event-e-which)

Answer (score 1):

use the event.keyCode

```
var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
 if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
   //Do something
 }
```

There is already a discussion in this link
[jQuery Event Keypress: Which key was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302122/jquery-event-keypress-which-key-was-pressed)

Answer (score 1):

These day you can do it, in this way:

```
document.getElementById('co').addEventListener('keydown',
  e => !e.repeat && e.keyCode === 13 && load());
```

Please notice that `load()` will run it once.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for showing me how to do a fat arrow function without the parentheses and curly braces: I didn't know that was possible. This is the solution I'm using in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good link that discusses this topic and provides a working examples

```
function DetectEnterPressed(e) {
var characterCode
if(e && e.which){ // NN4 specific code
e = e
characterCode = e.which
}
else {
e = event
characterCode = e.keyCode // IE specific code
}
if (characterCode == 13) return true // Enter key is 13
else return false
}
```

http://hspinfo.wordpress.com/2008/09/01/using-javascript-detect-enter-key-pressed-event-in-a-textbox-and-perform-the-action/

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and it works fine:

```
document.getElementById("theIdHere").onkeypressed = 
function() {
     if(this.event.which === 13)
        console('passed');
}
```