# How do I use the enter button in Html?

Tags: javascript, html

hey i'm making an chat program but I dont know how to assign the "enter" button to a onclick function.

```
<input id = "SendMessage" onclick="Send()" value = "Send" class = "Button" type = "submit">
```

thats my code. does someone have an awnser? Have a nice day!

Comment: May be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365632/how-to-detect-when-the-user-presses-enter-in-an-input-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `keydown` event listener like this:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");
input.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) { //13 is the keycode of ENTER
    Send();
  }
});

function Send(){
  alert(input.value + " - has been sent");
}
```

```html
<input id = "input" type="text"/>
<input id = "SendMessage" onclick="Send()" value = "Send" class = "Button" type = "submit">
```

Comment: can you make it so i can just copy paste it in my code? Im new to coding and it's sometimes hard to understand

Comment: Do i have to put the "var input = document.getElementById("input");
input.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) { //13 is the keycode of ENTER
    Send();
  }
});

function Send(){
  alert(input.value + " - has been sent");
}" in the script.js file?

Comment: I now got 2 message input's instead of 1?

Comment: @Jordydev I assumed there is a text input in your code because you want to send on enter press. Since you didn't post your full code including the text box and `Send` function I made them. if you want the enter to be recognized everywhere on the page use `document.addEventListener("keydown", event => { if (event.keyCode === 13) { //13 is the keycode of ENTER Send(); } });`