# how can i clear the text in the text box when the form is submitting through load() ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

I am trying to do comments so that after submitting the appending the data on the form! and the form is showing the comments that i sent previously.
This is my form of html

```
<table> 
<tr><td>Name :</td><td> <input type="text" id="name"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email :</td><td> <input type="email" id="email"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Comment:</td><td><textarea cols=50 rows=10 id="input_text" placeholder="Discuss here"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><button id="btn">Submit</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

and i am sending this form values to db through load() ajax function,

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").click(function(){
    var comments=$("#input_text").val();
    var name=$("#name").val();
    var email=$("#email").val();

 $("#hidden_div").load("insert.php",   {comments:comments,name:name,email:email},function(){
  $("#display").append($("#hidden_div").html());
      });
  } 
    });
  });
 </script>
 <div id="hidden_div" style="display:none"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `val` to set a new value for each form field, after you call the `load` function

```
$("#hidden_div").load(...);
$("#input_text, #name, #email").val('');
```

Comment: and i have one more question , how can i send input text value by pressing 'enter' to update the comment through load() ajax function!

Comment: without submit button!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060750/detect-the-enter-key-in-an-text-input-field

Answer (score 0):

Use this after your form submitted

```
$("input , textarea").val("");
```