# Capturing <Enter> press while in input field fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Problem Statement:** I have implemented code described in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7060762/4490559) Stack Overflow answer to try and capture a press of the answer key while a user is in a text `<input>`. The code works to capture the enter press, however, after enter is pressed, the function body keeps running. Essentially, as soon as the enter key is pressed, the function runs infinitely. **The ideal behavior of this is to have a user press Enter and then have the function called *once*.**

**What have I tried to solve my Problem?**

The following was my original jQuery.

```
$(function(){
    $("#maininput").keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            alert("Enter was Pressed while in input ")       
        }
    });
});
```

This ran infinitely after the Enter key was pressed. As a result of this, I started looking for more Stack Overflow entries, and I found threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) that talk about using `return false` or `e.preventDefault()`. I tried implementing `return false` and had the following code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#maininput").keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            alert("")       
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

However, even the `return false` didn't fix it. I then replaced `return false` with `e.preventDefault()` and that didn't work.  A JSFiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cznfnfsm/6/).

What is going wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: The fiddle is working (not looping). Perhaps you could add more to the fiddle to replicate your problem and in doing that you'll pinpoint the issue :)

Comment: Ohh... I see what is going on... (Now I have to figure out how to prevent it)

Comment: If you still need help, post your findings and you'll surely get an answer

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the code you posted will cause the `keyup` function to run repeatedly, but perhaps you need to debounce your function.

https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Also, you were on the right track with `return false` and `e.preventDefault()`. Here is a great explanation of the difference between the two:

https://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/