# How to detect Enter key press in this JavaScript exercise?

Tags: javascript

In this exercise of searching for products with JavaScript, I need to incorporate a function where when I type the name of a product and press the "Enter" key it shows me the element.

```
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("click", () => {
  //initializations
  let searchInput = document.getElementById("search-input").value;
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".product-name");
  let cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

  //loop through all elements
  elements.forEach((element, index) => {
    //check if text includes the search value
    if (element.innerText.includes(searchInput.toUpperCase())) {
      //display matching card
      cards[index].classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
      //hide others
      cards[index].classList.add("hide");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060750/detect-the-enter-key-in-a-text-input-field)

Comment: Please, [do some research, and show the results of the research in your question](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch), when asking a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

Basically you should create a function which will be called when you press enter and attach it to the event of the element.

```
function actionOnEnter(e: event) {
 const key = e.keyCode || e.which;

 if(key == 13) {
  doSomething()
 }
}
```

If you don't know what event to use, check this out: [onKeyPress Vs. onKeyUp and onKeyDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown#:%7E:text=onkeydown%20is%20fired%20when%20the,Ctrl%20is%20held%20%27down%27.&text=onkeypress%20is%20fired%20as%20a,onkeyup%20isn%27t%20fired).